# Routing between vlans with two routers

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, vlan

I'm making a simple exercise to understand how to route between vlans.
I have this setup, a router in the top where routing occurs and three vlans.

[image: Packet Tracer 7 visualization]

I've created the vlans and added encapsulation for each vlan in Router1 and attributed IP for the gateways accordingly.

Router1 has the following configuration:

```
Current configuration : 865 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.2
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 3
 ip address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.3
 encapsulation dot1Q 4
 ip address 192.168.3.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Switch0 has the following vlans configured:

```
Current configuration : 1091 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Switch1 has the following vlans configured:

```
Current configuration : 1288 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description connects to PC1
 switchport access vlan 3
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 description connects to Switch0
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 description connects to Switch2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 description connects to router1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Switch2 has the following vlans configured:

```
Current configuration : 1114 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 4
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

PC1 has the following configurations:

```
IP: 192.168.2.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.2.254
```

PC2 has the following configurations:

```
IP: 192.168.3.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.3.254
```

Wireless Router has the following configurations:

```
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.254
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

The laptop is getting dhcp from the wireless router.

Everyone should talk to anybody. Both PCs talk to each other and the laptop can reach the PCs. But I can't figure what is needed to make the PCs talk to the laptop or ping the wireless router successfully.

Here is my packet tracer 7 file:
[exercise_pkt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxt6AIcey5oTTkJZaTZxRlBwZ1k)

Comment: Most people here don't have packet Tracer, so you need to edit your question to include the network device configurations, what you have done to test, the results, what you have tried to do to remediate the problem, etc.

Comment: What you need to do is to use the `show running-configuration` command on each device, copy the the full configurations, paste them into the question, and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`). We need to see the full configurations. For instance, we don't see your trunk configuration. There are also other configurations that may affect this, but you have not provided them. Give us everything.

Comment: You are getting there. What is the configuration of the wireless router? Is it doing NAT? Since it is providing DHCP for the laptop, is it giving the laptop the correct gateway? We need to see the configuration to determine these types of things.

Comment: I also _strongly_ encourage you to use the `description` command on the interfaces. For example, you have no way to tell which of the three trunks on Switch 1 goes to which other network device. Also, there is no trunk on Switch 0. That means you are using DTP to determine the trunk, and that really isn't a good practice.

Comment: I'm going to figure out how to ping the wireless router first, from PC1 or PC2. I am almost there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem stems from the wireless router, which, unfortunately, is a consumer-grade device, so it is explicitly off-topic here. Likely, it is configured with a firewall that drops ICMP on the WAN interface, and it will not respond to ping. You will need to disable that if you want to ping. If the wireless router is performing NAT, then you will have a problem initiating traffic from outside to inside the router. You should disable NAT if you want to ping the laptop.

Also, you will need routes in both routers so that they know how to reach the networks on the other side of the other router. Routers learn routes in three ways:

- Directly connected networks
- Statically configured routes
- Dynamically from a routing protocol

Router1 will need to know that it should go to the wireless router in order to reach the network on the other side of the wireless router. You have not given use the network that you are using on the other side of the wireless router, so I will use `10.1.1.0/24` as an example. On Router1, you can use a static route:

```
ip route 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

On the wireless router, you will need to configure routes to `192.168.2.0/24` and 192.168.3.0/24`through`192.168.1.254`. The wireless router already knows how to reach the`192.168.1.0/24` network because it is directly connected to it.

For your other configurations, You should make some tweaks to follow best practices.

On Router1, you should set the host name to match the diagram. You will also need a password on the VTY lines if expect to connect to the router via telnet.

```
hostname Router1
!
line vty 0 15
 password MyRouter1Password
 login
!
```

On Switch0, you should configure a trunk interface for the interface that connects to Switch1. Use descriptions on the interfaces, including the one connected to the wireless router. Also, you will also need a password on the VTY lines if expect to connect to the switch via telnet.

```
hostname Switch0
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 description Connection to Wireless Router F0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 description Connection to Switch1 F0/22
 switchport mode trunk
!
line vty 0 15
 password MySwitch0Password
 login
!
```

On Switch1, use descriptions on the interfaces. Also, you will also need a password on the VTY lines if expect to connect to the switch via telnet.

```
hostname Switch1
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
 description Connection to Switch0 F0/24
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
 description Connection to Switch2 F0/24
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 description Connection to Router1 F0/1
 switchport mode trunk
!
line vty 0 15
 password MySwitch1Password
 login
!
```

On Switch2, use descriptions on the interfaces. Also, you will also need a password on the VTY lines if expect to connect to the switch via telnet.

```
hostname Switch2
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 description Connection to Switch1 F0/23
 switchport mode trunk
!
line vty 0 15
 password MySwitch2Password
 login
!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not included the housekeeping details because I wanted to focus on getting through the wireless router. Replacing the wireless router with a wired router works. However I was not successful in getting through the wireless one.

Comment: Well, things like descriptions on the interfaces can help a lot in troubleshooting. You could compare the CDP results with your description to make sure you have thing connected the way you intended.

Comment: On the wireless router - if it's so equipped, set it to run as a bridge.  The laptop should be running in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and referencing 192.168.1.254 as its default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

As inter-Vlan routing is enabled in perimeter router . By default PC's and laptops should ping each other . If not pi g mean check for

1. Any access -list Configured on perimeter router . If there Configured access -list as per requirement .
2. checks for window OS firewall status.  if it is windows firewall or if any other OS check for OS level firewall status . Ping should be allowed inbound and outbound.